# Abstract methods and the varargs annotation

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions, scala-java-interop

Scala provides a [`@varargs` annotation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.varargs) that generates a Java varargs forwarder method, which makes it possible to write something like this:

```
import scala.annotation.varargs

class Foo {
  @varargs def foo(args: String*): Unit = {
    args.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

And then to call this method from Java without needing to create a `scala.Seq`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.foo("a", "b");
```

Which is pretty nice.

Unfortunately the forwarding part doesn't seem to happen when the method is abstract:

```
trait Bar {
  @varargs def bar(args: String*): Unit
}

class Baz extends Bar {
  def bar(args: String*): Unit = {
    args.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Now if we have this Java code:

```
Bar bar = new Baz();
bar.bar("a", "b");
```

We get this exception (at runtime):

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Baz.bar([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

We can confirm the problem with `javap`:

```
public interface Bar {
  public abstract void bar(java.lang.String...);
  public abstract void bar(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>);
}

public class Baz implements Bar {
  public void bar(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>);
  public Baz();
}
```

So nope, the forwarder definitely isn't getting implemented.

Putting the annotation on both `bar` methods fails to compile:

```
A method with a varargs annotation produces a forwarder method with the same
signature (args: Array[String])Unit as an existing method.
```

And of course putting the annotation only on the `bar` in `Baz` means we can't use the forwarder from a `Bar` instance.

This seems like it must be a bug, but it also seems extremely easy to run into, and I'm not seeing anything in the issue tracker. Am I using `@varargs` correctly? If so, is there a workaround that would make it do what you'd expect here?

Comment: Oops. Seems to me another bug. Thanks to one another `jugaad` solution for interopability. Gosh! how many more are lying there?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Try submitting a new bug to their issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `Scala`, but in Java varargs is just an array.

So in Java it will work this way, with one warning:

```
package tests.StackOverflow.q27052394;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Runner {

    public interface Bar {
      public abstract void bar(java.lang.String ... ss);
    }

    public static class Baz implements Bar {
      public void bar(java.lang.String[] array) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bar b = new Baz();

        b.bar("hello", "world");

    }

}
```

May be if you can fool `Scala` the same way, you will overcome the bug.

Comment: Adding a method `def bar(args: Array[String]): Unit = bar(args: _*)` to `Baz` actually seems to work (although it's not very pleasant).

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to define interface in Java as follows

```
interface Bar {
  public void bar(String... args);
}
```

and then to define the implementation normally in Scala as follows

```
class Baz extends Bar {
  def bar(args: String*): Unit = {
    args.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Scala compiler will recognize that it needs to generate vargs style method and will generate both varargs and Seq implementation.

javap output is as you would expect

```
public class Baz implements Bar {
  public void bar(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>);
  public void bar(java.lang.String[]);
  public Baz();
}

interface Bar {
  public abstract void bar(java.lang.String...);
}
```